# Flutter: Setting constraints for package versions in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

I used [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) package, share pacakge document said add like this,

```
 share: ">=0.6.y+x <2.0.0"
```

**Please set your constraint to share: '>=0.6.y+x <2.0.0'**

after run pub get, I got this error,

```
Error on line 65, column 10 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Expected version number after ">=" in ">=0.6.y+x <2.0.0", got "0.6.y+x <2.0.0".

   ╷

65 │   share: ">=0.6.y+x <2.0.0"

   │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to the pub description of the package to get the exact versioning.

Or

Here's a short cut:

Try to give *"any"* instead of the version number in `pubspec.yaml` like:

```
share: any
```

Then go to `pubspec.lock`, you will find the latest version that the framework has picked for you.

[image]

You might not want to leave it as "any" because if anything changes in the future update, maybe new feature or some deprecation. Your code might crash. It is advised to take the version number from .lock file and pass it in .yaml file (exactly as is it shown in .lock).

**Setting constraints:**

If you want a specific update of the plugin then you can set constraint for the version number as follows:

```
plugin_name: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0' //change these values according to your specs
```

For your specific requirement:

```
share: '>=0.6.4+3 <2.0.0'
```

Comment: thanks, what is this meaning? Please set your constraint to share: '>=0.6.y+x <2.0.0'

Comment: It means that you have to set constraints, change the value of x+y with the latest version number. I have edited the answer check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it says to add it like this in the docs:

```
share: ^0.6.4+3
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks, what is this meaning? Please set your constraint to share: '>=0.6.y+x <2.0.0'